# Window Phone augmented reality and shape recognition

Tags: windows-phone, augmented-reality, emgucv, shape-recognition

I am a beginner in Windows Phone app development. My goal is to create a simple augmented reality application which will include shape recognition (ex. hand or face). Additionally I would like to draw 3D objects on screen and place them in reality. The question is what is the best way to start development? Especially which toolkits do You advise to use? My current idea is to detect motion using Motion Class built in WP-SDK and use EmguCV to dectect and recognise shapes. And which library should I use to draw shapes (Direct3d or XNA) ? Is it a good way to start? I am confused if EmguCV is available on Windows Phone platform at all?

Additional info:
- platform will be WP7.5 or WP8

Answer (score 0):

i'm working also on windows phone project, it was about face recognition but because lack libraries that can used in other things i change my project.
but there is FACESDK that could help you for Face recognition.
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/facesdk/